# How to get data from a particular CardView click and shown data in another activity

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have to get details when customer clicked cardview but isn't shown the data in my activity.

This is My code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MenuItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final int _index = position;

    holder.iBookingRef.setText(itemList.get(position).getBookingID());
    holder.iClientName.setText(itemList.get(position).getDelegeteName());
    holder.iHotelName.setText(itemList.get(position).getHotelName());

    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, ArrivalsActivity.class);

          intent.putExtra("BookingID", itemList.get(_index).getBookingID());
          intent.putExtra("DelegeteName", itemList.get(_index).getDelegeteName());
          intent.putExtra("HotelName", itemList.get(_index).getHotelName());

          context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use a callback(Interface) . If the list exist in another activity then you can use `BroadcastReceiver` or `EventBus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an Interface inside your adapter containing methods. And while implementing your Adapter, those methods will be implemented in your activity and you can perform whatever action you want.

```
 public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycleViewHolder> {

public interface Callbacks {
    public void onButtonClicked(String titleKey);
}

private Callbacks mCallbacks;

public Adapter() {

}

@Override
public MyRecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_details, null);
    return new MyRecycleViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecycleViewHolder holder, final int i) {

    holder.ExpandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks.onButtonClicked(holder.ProbTitle.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return;
}

public void setCallbacks(Callbacks callbacks) {
    this.mCallbacks = callbacks;
}
```

}

**OR**

you may try do this on your onItemClick()

```
Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
i.putExtra("title", yourTitle);
i.putExtra("description", yourDescription);
view.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

and when oncreate in your DetailActivity,do this

```
String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
```

so you can pass title and description to DetailActivity